# Query for selecting count(*) of a query but only return a LIMIT of the query result OFFSET by something

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL query which runs over multiple tables to return some columns and uses `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` for pagination.

I also have a second SQL query which is exactly the same as the first query except it returns the `count(*)` of the previous query *without* the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` operators.

Is is possible for me to perform this in one SQL statement? Can I improve upon what I have?

Examples of both queries:

1. `SELECT a.col1, b.col4, c.col5 FROM a, b, c LIMIT 20 OFFSET 5`
2. `SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT a.col1, b.col4, c.col5 FROM a, b, c) t`

Comment: Are you aware that `FROM a, b, c` will generate a cartesian product of the three tables?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am aware. Thanks for pointing that out though. That was the shortest example I could come up with. I'm extensively using `LEFT JOIN`s in my real queries.

Comment: @davidkonrad "Make it a view and query over that" - interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a.col1, 
       b.col4, 
       c.col5,
       count(*) over () as total_count
FROM a
  JOIN b ON ..
  JOIN c ON ...
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 5
```

Note that I replaced the (most probably) incorrect `FROM a, b, c` with a proper join between the three tables.

Comment: Are you sure it will count the whole set without the limit? As I understand that is the requirement.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto:I wasn't sure as well, but a quick test showed that this works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/389de/2

Comment: Cool. Tested it and it works. Also [link to the postgresql docs on the window feature.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html) The count is prepended to every row.

Answer (score 1):

```
with s as (
    select a.col1, b.col4, c.col5
    from a, b, c
), c as (
    select count(*) as c
    from s
)
select col1, col4, col5, (select c from c) as _count
from s
limit 20 offset 5
```

Comment: Tested. This also works. I modified my query to return `(select c from c) as _count, s.* from s`, which is more concise than saying col1, col4, col5. Thanks!